# What was happening with the time freezer device?

Tags: plot-explanation, artemis-fowl

I am talking about Disney's [Artemis Fowl.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3089630/)

**Might be spoilers**

In the movie fairies use a time freezing machine in order to stop the motion of humans.

When the troll loses control for the first time, it's shown that fairies used it to stop motion for all people in a marriage ceremony and captured the troll.

Later, when the fairies used the devices on Fowl Manor it **doesn't freeze Artemis, Domovoi and Juliet**.

[image]

Secondly, when time freeze machine turned unstable Foaly was shouting

> There goes another fairy

What did he mean by that? Were those fairies dying? Were those fairies taken back to their world? Were they gone into unknown?

[image]

Please help me understand.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what happened during this bit. I can only assume that they were sent forward/back in time, but given this didn't happen in the books (then again, nor did a lot of stuff in the film) it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @tombull89 I guess the movie has lot of plot holes. For example, they didn't clear the memory of that fisherman who got stuck in the time barrier. Why time freezer didn't work on Artemis is another mystery.